# Eclipse and Collabnet Subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have installed Collabnet Subversion on Eclipse in order to connect to out Collabnet server.

At present there is only one developer so there is not problem of clashing.

However, now we are adding multiple developers. Each one will be developing sections of one application.
How do I organise the project?
I can't have them checking out the whole project each time because they will lose any updates they have - if I am correct.

Should I split the aplication in such a way that each section is in a separate package. This way a programmer can import sections of the application that have been updated by another programmer without having to import the whole application each time.

Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. Each developer can just check out the whole project once. When they want to get changes that others have made, they run "update" and svn will replace/merge any modified files. There is no danger of losing changes. Even if multiple people edit the same file it will usually merge automatically, and if not, manual merge is available.

You should organize your application code by function. If this corresponds with "sections" that single developers will be working on, that's fine, but it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Question is, would there be any circumstances where a programmer would want updates from one other programmer but not from a third?

Comment: If this answer is yes then look into git.